# String can not recognize with whitespaces or as empty

Tags: java

Before I begin to discuss my issue, I REALLY (and I do mean REALLY) researched for hours on my solution but I couldn't find it or understand it clearly; after my second career question was down-voted, a lot, I was skeptical of posting my current code of a free lance project for a portfolio. If I look like a beginner, that's because I am; I'm also embarrassed of my current progress.

But enough: I'm creating a project of a potential distributing company and I want to add restriction to the strings. How do I prevent the code to continue before finding the spaces/empty string?

```
    public class AddOrder {
static Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
//Blocking special character input

 private static CharSequence s1 = "!";
 private static CharSequence s2 = "@";
 private static CharSequence s3 = "#";
 private static CharSequence s4 = "$";
 private static CharSequence s5 = "%";
 private static CharSequence s6 = "^";
 private static CharSequence s7 = "&";
 private static CharSequence s8 = "*";
 private static CharSequence s9 = "(";
 private static CharSequence s10 = ")";
 private static CharSequence s11 = "_";
 private static CharSequence s12 = "=";
 private static CharSequence s13 = "+";
 private static CharSequence s14 = "[";
 private static CharSequence s15 = "]";
 private static CharSequence s16 = "{";
 private static CharSequence s17 = "}";
 private static CharSequence s18 = ";";
 private static CharSequence s19 = ":";
 private static CharSequence s20 = "'";
 private static CharSequence s21 = "?";
 private static CharSequence s22 = "<";
 private static CharSequence s23 = ">";
 private static CharSequence s24 = "/";
 private static CharSequence s25 = "`";
 private static CharSequence s26 = "~";
 private static CharSequence s27 = " ";
 private static CharSequence s28 = ".";

 //Blocking special character input


public static void informationPrompt(){

    System.out.println("Please insert following information:");
    System.out.println("Last Name, First Name, Middle Initial");
    System.out.println("Street Address");
    System.out.println("Zip code, City, State, Country");
}
public static void setLastname(){
    System.out.println("Please enter: Last Name");
    String lastName = input.nextLine();

    for (int i = 0; i < lastName.length(); i++){
        if (lastName.length() > 50 || lastName.isEmpty() || Character.isWhitespace(i) || Character.isDigit(lastName.charAt(i)) || lastName.contains(s1)||  lastName.contains(s2)
        || lastName.contains(s3) || lastName.contains(s4) || lastName.contains(s5) || lastName.contains(s6) || lastName.contains(s7) || lastName.contains(s8)
        || lastName.contains(s9) || lastName.contains(s10) || lastName.contains(s11) || lastName.contains(s12) || lastName.contains(s13) || lastName.contains(s14)
        || lastName.contains(s15) || lastName.contains(s16) || lastName.contains(s17) || lastName.contains(s18) || lastName.contains(s19) || lastName.contains(s20)
        || lastName.contains(s21) || lastName.contains(s22) || lastName.contains(s23) || lastName.contains(s24) || lastName.contains(s25) || lastName.contains(s26)){
            System.out.println("Incorrect input. Either:\n"
                    + "1: Fill in last name.\n"
                    + "2: Numerics are not allowed; please remove numbers\n"
                    + "3: Name is longer than 50 characters; please shorten.\n"
                    + "4: No special characters are allowed (e.g: !,@,#,$, etc.);"
                    + "please remove special characters\n"
                    + "5: No spaces (whitespaces) are allowed; Please fill in without spaces.");                    
            setLastname();
        }

        }
    }
```

It's a mess, I know. Any advice/suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered using a [regex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) for this?

Comment: From the System.out.println("Incorrect input..."); numbers 1 & 5 are not checked. Everything else should be ok, I think...

Comment: Almost the entirety of your first paragraph is noise to the question. State that you are beginner, remove the rest.

Comment: I have, PakkuDon. But as of now, I'm certainly not confident in regex. I actually have been studying it for the past 2 days, but no avail, mentally.

Comment: Sorry about that, Sotirios.

Comment: You can edit your question. How are you checking for whitespace?

Comment: Just a suggestion, wouldn't an array of CharSequences be better?

Comment: Actually, I tried that, ModDL! lol! But it created compile errors. I forgot what and where; that was my first method.

Comment: Why are you looping over the entered strings a number of times equal to the number of characters in the string?

Comment: Because I'm assuming that, instead of looping through the string, it's "going through" the string in respect to i to check each entered character; my interpretation of a "for" loop may be wrong.

Comment: Look up the `String` class' javadoc.

Comment: Are you speaking of this site, Sotirios: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum Or are you kindly telling me to research the String class entirely? If so, I can take that. :-D I did see a lot of help in regards to regex; simply explained actually...! I'll try it tonight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own question. I just separated the .isEmpty() method from the ugly mosh pit of what I call exceptions and used the Character class in respect to i and the lastName String (Character.isWhitespace(lastName.charAt(i)) :

```
    public static void setLastname(){
    System.out.println("Please enter: Last Name");
    String lastName = input.nextLine();
    if (lastName.isEmpty()){
    System.out.println("Incorrect input. Either:\n"
            + "1: Fill in last name.\n"
            + "2: Numerics are not allowed; please remove numbers\n"
            + "3: Name is longer than 50 characters; please shorten.\n"
            + "4: No special characters are allowed (e.g: !,@,#,$, etc.);"
            + "please remove special characters\n"
            + "5: No spaces (whitespaces) are allowed; Please fill in without spaces.");                    
    setLastname();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < lastName.length(); i++){
        if (lastName.length() > 50 || Character.isWhitespace(lastName.charAt(i)) || Character.isDigit(lastName.charAt(i)) || lastName.contains(s1)||  lastName.contains(s2)
        || lastName.contains(s3) || lastName.contains(s4) || lastName.contains(s5) || lastName.contains(s6) || lastName.contains(s7) || lastName.contains(s8)
        || lastName.contains(s9) || lastName.contains(s10) || lastName.contains(s11) || lastName.contains(s12) || lastName.contains(s13) || lastName.contains(s14)
        || lastName.contains(s15) || lastName.contains(s16) || lastName.contains(s17) || lastName.contains(s18) || lastName.contains(s19) || lastName.contains(s20)
        || lastName.contains(s21) || lastName.contains(s22) || lastName.contains(s23) || lastName.contains(s24) || lastName.contains(s25) || lastName.contains(s26)) {
            System.out.println("Incorrect input. Either:\n"
                    + "1: Fill in last name.\n"
                    + "2: Numerics are not allowed; please remove numbers\n"
                    + "3: Name is longer than 50 characters; please shorten.\n"
                    + "4: No special characters are allowed (e.g: !,@,#,$, etc.);"
                    + "please remove special characters\n"
                    + "5: No spaces (whitespaces) are allowed; Please fill in without spaces.");                    
            setLastname();
        }

        }
    }
```

Now it looks much worse and "newbish" than before. Me trying to prove to others and myself that an electrical engineering student can keep up with the big CS boys, and girls. Thank you all for your input. I just feel sorry for the person who's going to inspect my code later this week! lol!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a look at an ascii [table](http://www.asciitable.com/) you will see that the input you want A-Z or a-z runs in the sequential numbering of 65-90 and 97-122

Sometime working on what is allowed is better than what is NOT allowed.

Other people have suggested a regex `String expression = "^[a-zA-Z\\s]+";` which will work for very very basic names.

Also the checks for length and empty only needs to be done once.

Comment: This is the most common regex example I found. I have NO problem changing my code, trust me! But I simply do not know how to implement it.

Comment: As per the `String` above,  `boolean ok = Pattern.matches(expression, lastName);`